# SQL group concat with duplicate ID's

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to concat the week_num from a table, grouping bby Driver_id. But group_concat will not keep duplicate ID's, but My requirement is to have them.
Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: I edited the tags. The OP clarified in a comment that they are using Amazon Redshift, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use subquery & self-join

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t2.*,t1.Consolidate_weeks
FROM (
    SELECT Driver_id,GROUP_CONCAT(Week_num) Consolidate_weeks
    FROM T
    GROUP BY Driver_id
) t1 INNER JOIN T t2
ON t1.Driver_id = t2.Driver_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5093a/2/0)**:

```
| Driver_id | Week_num | Consolidate_weeks |
|-----------|----------|-------------------|
|         1 |   Week 1 |     Week 1,Week 2 |
|         2 |   Week 1 |     Week 1,Week 2 |
|         3 |   Week 1 |     Week 1,Week 2 |
|         4 |   Week 1 |     Week 1,Week 2 |
|         1 |   Week 2 |     Week 1,Week 2 |
|         2 |   Week 2 |     Week 1,Week 2 |
|         3 |   Week 2 |     Week 1,Week 2 |
|         4 |   Week 2 |     Week 1,Week 2 |
```

**Edit**

I saw your comment & edited the question, if you are using amazon-redshift you can try to use [LISTAGG](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html) instead `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Thank you,
but I got the below error each time I use Group_concat.
Invalid operation: function group_concat(character varying) does not exist; [SQL State=42883, DB Errorcode=500310]

Comment: are you sure that you are using mysql?

Comment: Using AWS redshift

Comment: Redshift is not MySQL. It is an Amazon product based largely on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your Time,
I'm a Newbie, found a way listagg to resolve.